# Experience in war vs on war

Tags: prepositions

My question is that should we say I have experience in war or I have experience on war?
Please, clear the fog in my head. Thanks

Comment: Did you fight or write a thesis?

Comment: Though *"experience on wars"* is more likely, *"I have experience on war"* sounds unfamiliar to me. I am more familiar with *"I went to the Korean war,"* *"I have experienced the wars,"* or even *"I have the experience of warfare."* (which means something entirely different).

Comment: @mplungian  Succinctly put!  +1

Answer (score 2):

"On" seems to suggest that you were covering or talking about war, while "in" suggests something more along the lines of participation in battle.